# Find order of points along polyline

Tags: qgis-3, linear-referencing, order, sequential

I have a points layer with random points located along a route (polyline layer). I was wondering if there is a simple way to give a sequence number to each point in the order they show up along the route.

I am using QGIS 3.8, but I am very green and struggle with the lingo. I did install the LRS plugin hoping it might be a straight forward solution for me, but I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 8):

If your route (polyline) layer's name is `Route1` which has an id field (`fid`), and the point layer is `Bears` like below example.

[image]

Open the attribute table of the `Bears` (point) layer and start the Field Calculator.

[image]

Create a new field (`Dist`) which shows the distance along the line by an expression:

```
line_locate_point(geometry:=geometry(get_feature('Route1','fid','1')), point:=$geometry)
```

Then start **Add autoincremental field** *(Processing Toolbox > Vector table)*.

[image]

Choose the distance field you have just calculated as **Sort expression**.

I think you should set the start value at `1`, otherwise the first bear will get the number zero like below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I have not been able to try this until now.  This worked perfectly! Thank you Kazuhito. Thanks also to @taras for chiming in.